# Visual Studio - DLL dependency not found DESPITE Environment variable being set

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

I have written a C application that depends on a few DLLs and am having some trouble when using the local debugger. It's this well documented error message:

> "This program can't start because xxx.dll is missing from your
>   computer."

Right now it's portaudio_x86.dll but the DLL is arbitrary as I'm getting the same behaviour for a bunch of others (libfftw3-3.dll, libsamplerate-0.dll, libsndfile-1.dll...)

I have been to Configuration Properties\Debugging  and changed the Environment to:

PATH =

> C:\portaudioASIO\portaudio\lib;%PATH%

(where the portaudio dll is) 
and Merge Environment is 'Yes' (I've tried every combination and permutation of the PATH with appending, prepending, having `$(ProjectDir)` in the mix - all to no avail)

but this doesn't resolve it and I still get the error message "dll not found" when I debug.

I'm currently working around it by including the DLLs in the debug folder but this seems like a bit of a hack to me and from reading all the other posts [ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/visual-studio-how-to-set-path-to-dll), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953843/why-cant-visual-studio-find-my-dll), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518082/dll-dependency-not-found-when-debugging-with-visual-studio-11-rc) ] about setting the Environment PATH variable I can't see why it doesn't work.

Any tips on how to get the PATH variable to behave properly ? Cheers!

This is using MSVS Community 2015, the app is in C but the same thing happens with a C++ version.

Comment: What happens if you copy the libraries into the same path where your executable is ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yup that's what I'm doing right now and it works fine. I don't see why the PATH variable method doesn't work though

Comment: Try the following on cmd prompt:  `echo %PATH%` just to check whether the `PATH` variable is modified correctly. Also try restarting the PC after modifying the variable.

Comment: Are you running from a cmd prompt - 32 or 64bit?

Comment: @cup This is using the debugger in the Visual Studio IDE, not from a cmd prompt. The app is 32 bit.

Comment: @sameerkn This isn't editing the PATH variable for the PC, it's just setting the path being searched by the debugger. That's my understanding anyway. 
I have just tried adding it to the system PATH variable though - and Visual Studio is still giving the "dll not found" error

Comment: If the PATH is changed, VS needs to be restarted otherwise the new path will not be picked up.

Comment: @cup this is not changing the Windows Environment Path - it is just appending the path to the DLL to the Windows Path. So `%PATH%` is the Windows Path and I am telling the debugger to use `C:\portaudioASIO\portaudio\lib; %PATH%` so it should see both the DLL Path and the windows Path.
and this is still throwing the "dll not found" error

Comment: ok so I made a mistake earlier - adding the directory to the Windows Environment Path does fix the problem. I hadn't restarted Visual Studio that time. BUT adding the path in Visual Studio is still not correctly modifying the Path that the debugger uses which is what I want to fix

Comment: So are you changing Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging, Environment to set the path?  Is Merge Environment set to "yes"

Comment: @cup Yup, that's exactly what I've done. For some reason it's not working correctly and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I haven't tampered with any other settings - all I've asked for is Visual Studio to also include the DLL directory along with the system path but it's not doing that